# data with the chart does not fit in highcharts js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm making a chart with [highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/) but I find it difficult when the chart is displayed not in accordance with the existing data.

I have created a chart on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3n1bzuL/).

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                            zoomType: 'xy'
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        colors: ['#ff0000', '#18b55b'],
                        xAxis: [{
                                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agu', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Des']
                            }],
                        yAxis: [{
                                min: 0,
                                labels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: '',
                                }
                            }, {
                                min: 0,
                                title: {
                                    text: '',
                                },
                                labels: {
                                    formatter: function () {
                                        return this.value + '%';
                                    }
                                }
                            }],
                        plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 10,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }],
                        tooltip: {
                            shared: true,
                            useHTML: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                                var s = '<table>';
                                $.each(this.points, function () {
                                    s += '<b style="text-align: right; color: ' + this.series.color + '">' + this.y + '%' + this.point.value + '</b><br/>';
                                });
                                return s;
                            },
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                        },
                        legend: {
                            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
                        },
                        series: [{"name":"Aktual","type":"column","yAxis":1,"data":[{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":12.06
,"value":" - 122,890,156"},{"y":2.66,"value":" - 27,080,668"},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},
{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0
,"value":""}]},{"name":"Plan","type":"spline","data":[{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":2.17
,"value":""},{"y":2.17,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value"
:""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""},{"y":0,"value":""}]}]
                    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear

Comment: sorry i'm newbie. thank you for correcting my question

Comment: Not sure what you mean...but it's vaxing that you show the Plan-series on xAxis0 while hiding xAxis0 (so you associate the point-values of the Plan-series  with the "wrong" value from the xAxis1). 
Maybe you want it to look somehting like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s3n1bzuL/1/

Comment: Let us know how this chart should look like and what is wrong with current